# Upgrade from Angular 9 to 11, only issue with tests which don't get executed

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, upgrade

I upgraded from Angular 9 to 11, after having installed ESlint and fixed all warning and issues, the project now get served and built successfully, only issue I got now it's with running unit test

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "description": "projectname web-based clients",
  "author": "company Ltd",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve projectname -o --watch",
    "build": "ng build projectname --prod",
    "build:stats": "ng build projectname --prod --stats-json",
    "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer target/dist/stats.json",
    "serve:cloud": "ng serve projectname --proxy-config proxy.conf.cloud.js",
    "test": "ng test projectname",
    "test:local": "ng test projectname --karmaConfig=karma.conf.local.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "9.0.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "angular-web-storage": "^9.0.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.472.0",
    "babylonjs": "^4.0.0",
    "babylonjs-gui": "^4.0.3",
    "bootstrap-css-only": "^4.1.3",
    "bowser": "^2.4.0",
    "dropbox": "^4.0.30",
    "jszip": "^3.2.2",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^13.0.1",
    "phaser": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.3",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-mockito": "^2.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

**Karma**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    reporters: ['spec', 'junit'],
    
    specReporter: {
      maxLogLines: 5,             // limit number of lines logged per test
      suppressErrorSummary: true, // do not print error summary
      suppressFailed: false,      // do not print information about failed tests
      suppressPassed: false,      // do not print information about passed tests
      suppressSkipped: true,      // do not print information about skipped tests
      showSpecTiming: false,      // print the time elapsed for each spec
    },
    // karma-junit-reporter config (https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-junit-reporter#configuration)
    junitReporter: {
      // REPORTS_DIRECTORY environment variable is expected to be defined in pom.xml
      // (see https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/)
      outputDir: process.env.REPORTS_DIRECTORY || 'target/karma-reports/',
      outputFile: 'TESTS.frontend-NAME.xml',
      suite: 'frontend-NAME', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
      nameFormatter: (browser, result) => result.description,
      // group all tests inside 'eu.COMPANY.PROJECT.ui' package, for better Jenkins visualization
      classNameFormatter: (browser, result) => 'eu.COMPANY.PROJECT.ui.' + result.suite.join('.')
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['ChromiumHeadless'],
    singleRun: true,
  });
};
```

**Karma local**

```
// import base config file
var baseConfig = require('./karma.conf.js');

// export settings
module.exports = function (config) {
  // load base config
  baseConfig(config);
  // then the overrides
  config.set({
    // append to existing plugings
    plugins: config.plugins.concat([
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
    ]),
    // append to existing reporters
    reporters: config.reporters.concat(['progress', 'kjhtml']),
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/PROJECT'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

The error getting after having run the **local config** is:

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...09 03 2021 08:46:11.693:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
09 03 2021 08:46:11.705:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.1.1 server started at http://localhost:9876/
09 03 2021 08:46:11.706:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
09 03 2021 08:46:11.709:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
09 03 2021 08:46:44.644:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
09 03 2021 08:46:44.854:INFO [Chrome 89.0.4389.82 (Mac OS 10.15.6)]: Connected on socket VrX_mqflyya8IEbsAAAB with id 6097681
Chrome 89.0.4389.82 (Mac OS 10.15.6): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 89.0.4389.82 (Mac OS 10.15.6) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
Chrome 89.0.4389.82 (Mac OS 10.15.6) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Script error.
Chrome 89.0.4389.82 (Mac OS 10.15.6): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 89.0.4389.82 (Mac OS 10.15.6) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
Chrome 89.0.4389.82 (Mac OS 10.15.6): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.013 secs / 0 secs)
```

Error in the console of the opened Karma tab

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Module.W7Qn (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/testkit/mobile-import/mobile-import-test-data.ts:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:84)
    at Module.b8+U (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/common/modals/mobile-import-modal/mobile-import-modal.component.spec.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:84)
    at webpackContext (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src sync \.spec\.ts$:51)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Module.CB3P (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/test.ts:29)
    at __webpack_require__ (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:84)
    at checkDeferredModules (:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:45)
```

Comment: I am thinking something is wrong with the configuration of karma but not sure exactly what it is. The best advice I have for you is to generate a blank Angular 11 project and run the tests that it comes with it and if that works, see what's the difference between this blank project and your project. It could be the configuration or a package in package.json needs an upgrade.

Comment: @AliF50 I have already done it :/